# Raspberry Pi Jessie import error timezone

Tags: linux, python-3.x, timezone, raspberry-pi, importerror

Im trying to configure onedrive-d and im getting the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/onedrive-d", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('onedrive-d==1.1.0dev', 'console_scripts', 'onedrive-d')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
    ['__name__'])
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/onedrive_d/od_main.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/onedrive_d/od_glob.py", line 13, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name timezone
```

On the github instructions it says one of the pre-requisites are "your local filesystem must store UTC timestamps, not local time."

so i was wondering is this the cause of this error and if so is their anything i can do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates that the code expects Python 3 executable but you run it using Python 2.7. Run the installer using Python 3 e.g., `python3 -mpip --user install <package-name>`.

*"your local filesystem must store UTC timestamps, not local time"* has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: Thanks for your help but apparently i just needed to do a clean re-install.